# Workmanager does not execute unique jobs with APPEND policy

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I've found this weird behaviour of work manger (alpha-12) that it does not execute a job after it was enqueued. The code to enqueue the work is below.

```
fun enqueue(phoneNumber: String?,priorityId: String? = null): ListenableFuture<WorkInfo> {
    return WorkManager.getInstance().run {
        val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ContentDownloaderWork>()
            .addTag(TIMESTAMP)
            .setInputData(workDataOf(PHONE to phoneNumber, PRIORITY_ID to priorityId))
            .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
            .build()
        beginUniqueWork(TIMESTAMP + priorityId.orEmpty(), ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, work).enqueue()
        getWorkInfoById(work.id)
    }
}
```

I enqueue this work each time on app startup. And what I am doing is killing my app in the middle of the work process that is downloading files from server. It successfully restart every time I reopen my app but for limited number of times.

It seems like it has some sort of queue which gets filled up and does not allow any more jobs to be enqueued. When I check all available jobs by tag it show me that some are canceled and some succeeded but when I try to enqueue a new work it does nothing.

So is it a bug in workmanager or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your Worker ever return `Result.failure()`? Because a failed work chain can't be appended to.

Comment: @ianhanniballake No, it's either retry or success. But what result is going to be stored if the app process is killed?

Answer (score 0):

One important information that is missing in your description is the Android version that you're using in these tests.
WorkManager schedule workers using the JobScheduler API on Android Marshmallow (6.0, API Level 23) and newer, and it schedules a maximum amount of workers using this API at any time ([default is 20](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration#MIN_SCHEDULER_LIMIT), [maximum is 50](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Builder#setMaxSchedulerLimit(int))). The threshold you're seeing may be linked to this value.

Another important point, is that WorkManager keeps tracks of your workers for you so, if the application is killed while the worker is running, WorkManager automatically restart the worker. You don't need to do anything.

What is not clear to me, is what are you trying to achieve appending a new job every time at the application startup.

Last point, the backoff criteria of 1 second seems a bit aggressive to me. [The current default value, looking into the source code, is 30 seconds and the maximum is 5 hours](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/WorkRequest.java#L37).

However, if you think that there're something wrong (or documented incorrectly) I suggest you to open a bug on [WorkManager's public issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197).,